# In the Amazon EC2, is a Large Instance with SQL Express covered under a Reserved Instance with Windows and SQL?

Tags: amazon-ec2

We bought a m1.large Reserved Instance today, Windows with SQL Server for a year.

Now, I am wondering if a m1.large instance with SQL Express is covered under that Reserved Instance, or if a Instance with SQL standard has to be purchased.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your first reserved instance purchase, you can find out if it's covering a running instance by waiting a few hours, then checking the account activity to see if you are being charged for "Amazon EC2 running [...] Reserved Instances".  It will be split out as a separate charge with hours listed:

> https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/

Comment: It is not covered. It is necessary to go with SQL standard.